# Return all values from table if query string is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

Ok...so I have a page that lists products from a table based on the querystring.

So if I say **foo.aspx?fam=1** all the products from family **1** will be listed.

How can I make my code list all the values if query string is empty?

My SQL command would have to be different...can't really see how I can do this.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ds_produtos" runat="server" 
   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LocalSqlServer2 %>" 

    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [IdProduct], [Name], [Description], [IdFamily], [Price],  [Stock] FROM [Product] WHERE ([IdFamily] = @IdFamily )">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="IdFamily" QueryStringField="fam" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a default value for the property so that it has a value when you don't pass any value to the page:

```
<asp:QueryStringParameter Name="IdFamily" QueryStringField="fam" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="-1" />
```

Use the default value in the query:

```
SelectCommand="select IdProduct, [Name], Description, IdFamily, Price, Stock from Product where IdFamily = @IdFamily or @IdFamily = -1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to

`SELECT DISTINCT [IdProduct], [Name], [Description], [IdFamily], [Price],  [Stock] FROM [Product] WHERE ([IdFamily] = @IdFamily OR @IdFamily Is NULL)`

and pass null when there is no value specified for fam.

Comment: Make sure that CancelSelectOnNullParameter is set to false.